# pymongo sort and find_one issue

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to sort a collection called `user_score` using the key `position` and get the very first document of the result. In this case the collection `user_score` doesn't exist and I was hoping to get the result as `None`, but i was getting a cursor back.

1.
result =

```
db.user_score.find({'score':'$lt':score}}).sort("position,pymongo.DESCENDING").limit(1)
```

Now i changed my query like below and did not get anything as expected.

2.
result =

```
db.user_score.find_one({'score':{'$lt':score}}, sort=[("position", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

What's the problem with my first query?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your first query, in the sort function you're passing one argument `("position,pymongo.DESCENDING")`, when you should be passing two arguments `("position", pymongo.DESCENDING)`.

Be sure to mind your quotation marks.

Answer (score 24):

A little late in my response but it appears that the current version of PyMongo does support a [sort](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort) operation on a find_one call.

From the documentation page [here](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one):

> All arguments to find() are also valid arguments for find_one(),
> although any limit argument will be ignored. Returns a single
> document, or None if no matching document is found.

Example usage is as follows:

```
filterdict = {'email' : 'this.is@me.com'}
collection.find_one(filterdict, sort=[('lastseen', 1)])
```

Hope this helps more recent searchers!

Answer (score 2):

This is the default mongodb behavior on find. Whenever you use `find` you get a list of the results (in this case an iterable cursor). Only `findOne` or its PyMongo equivalent `find_one` will return `None` if the query has no matches.

Answer (score -3):

Use list to convert the value of the cursor into a dict:
list(db.user_score.find({'score':'$lt':score}}).sort("position",pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1))[0]

Comment: This was the way I solved it too. find_one doesn't take .sort, but find() does, so sorting, limiting and getting the first list item was the way to go